How to ensure videos autoplay and play inline in a card carousel on mobile devices?
I am building a vertical card carousel where each card has a video background. It works perfectly on desktop browsers (videos autoplay and play inline as expected), but on mobile browsers the videos fail to autoplay reliably.
I have ensured the following:
HTML attributes: The muted, playsinline, and preload="auto" attributes are set on each <video> tag.
Explicit muting in JavaScript: I programmatically set video.muted = true for each video.
Autoplay attempt in JavaScript: Using video.play() after a user interaction or on page load.
Despite these efforts, videos don't show until interacted with on a phone.
Autoplay: Ensure videos autoplay seamlessly on smaller devices.
Play inline: Prevent videos from opening in fullscreen on mobile.
Inactive cards: Ensure inactive cards show the first frame of the video as a still image while paused.


const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const body = document.body;
const elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-button, .elementor-widget-container a img');
let currentIndex = 0;
let isScrolling = false;
let touchStartY = 0;
let touchEndY = 0;

const bodyColors = ['#191d1c', '#534d3f', '#959185', '#bdb8b4', '#bec5bd'];

// Funksjon for å oppdatere styling på spesifikke elementer
function updateElementStyles() {
  const activeCard = cards[currentIndex];
  const cardTitle = activeCard.querySelector('h2').textContent.trim();
  const highlightCards = ['Om oss', 'Kultur']; // Kortene som skal trigge effekten

  if (highlightCards.includes(cardTitle)) {
    // Endre utseendet for de valgte elementene
    elementsToChange.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.tagName === 'IMG') {
        el.style.filter = 'invert(1)'; // Øk lysstyrken for bilder
      } else {
        el.style.color = '#ffffff'; // Sett tekstfarge til hvit
        el.style.transition = 'color 0.5s ease, filter 0.5s ease'; // Glatt overgang
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Tilbakestill til standard utseende
    elementsToChange.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.tagName === 'IMG') {
        el.style.filter = 'invert(0)'; // Tilbakestill lysstyrken
      } else {
        el.style.color = ''; // Tilbakestill tekstfarge
      }
    });
  }
}

function updateCards() {
  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    const relativeIndex = (index - currentIndex + cards.length) % cards.length;
    const video = card.querySelector('video');

    if (relativeIndex === 0) {
      card.className = 'card active';
      video.play();
      body.style.backgroundColor = bodyColors[index];
    } else {
      card.className =
        relativeIndex === 1 ? 'card behind' :
        relativeIndex === 2 ? 'card behind-2' :
        relativeIndex === 3 ? 'card behind-3' :
        relativeIndex === 4 ? 'card behind-4' :
        'card ahead';
      video.pause();
    }
  });

  updateElementStyles(); // Oppdater styling på de valgte elementene
}

function handleScroll(direction) {
  if (isScrolling) return;
  isScrolling = true;

  if (direction === 'down') {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % cards.length;
  } else if (direction === 'up') {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + cards.length) % cards.length;
  }

  updateCards();
  setTimeout(() => (isScrolling = false), 600); // Prevent rapid scroll/swipe
}

window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  handleScroll(e.deltaY > 0 ? 'down' : 'up');
});

// Touch events for mobile
window.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  touchStartY = e.touches[0].clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
  touchEndY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
  if (touchStartY > touchEndY + 50) {
    handleScroll('down'); // Swipe up
  } else if (touchStartY < touchEndY - 50) {
    handleScroll('up'); // Swipe down
  }
});

updateCards();
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Neue Montreal", sans-serif;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .c-cards__media {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.card .c-cards__media video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card .c-cards__media-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.card h2,
.card h3,
.card h4 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.card h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card h3 {
  font-size: 120px;
}

.card h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card {
  transform: translateY(50px) scale(0.8);
}

.card.active {
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  z-index: 5;
}

.card.behind {
  transform: translateY(-80px) scale(0.9);
  z-index: 4;
}

.card.behind-2 {
  transform: translateY(-150px) scale(0.8);
  z-index: 3;
}

.card.behind-3 {
  transform: translateY(-215px) scale(0.7);
  z-index: 2;
}

.card.behind-4 {
  transform: translateY(-275px) scale(0.6);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card.ahead {
  transform: translateY(300px) scale(0.9);
  z-index: 0;
}
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="cards">
    <a href="https://ozeta.loddo.no/om-oss/" class="card">
      <div class="c-cards__media">
        <video muted="true" loop playsinline preload="auto">
            <source src="https://ozeta.loddo.no/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/about.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="c-cards__media-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-cards__content">
        <h2>Om oss</h2>
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <h4>Learn More</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://ozeta.loddo.no/kultur/" class="card">
      <div class="c-cards__media">
        <video muted="true" loop playsinline preload="auto">
          <source src="https://ozeta.loddo.no/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/culture.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="c-cards__media-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-cards__content">
        <h2>Kultur</h2>
        <h3>Culture</h3>
        <h4>Explore More</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://ozeta.loddo.no/prototype/" class="card">
      <div class="c-cards__media">
        <video muted="true" loop playsinline preload="auto">
          <source src="https://ozeta.loddo.no/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/prototyping.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="c-cards__media-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-cards__content">
        <h2>Prototyping</h2>
        <h3>Prototype</h3>
        <h4>Discover</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://ozeta.loddo.no/produksjon/" class="card">
      <div class="c-cards__media">
        <video muted="true" loop playsinline preload="auto">
          <source src="https://ozeta.loddo.no/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/production-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="c-cards__media-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-cards__content">
        <h2>Produksjon</h2>
        <h3>Production</h3>
        <h4>Details</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://ozeta.loddo.no/baerekraft/" class="card">
      <div class="c-cards__media">
        <video muted="true" loop playsinline preload="auto">
          <source src="https://ozeta.loddo.no/wp-content/uploads/2024/12/production-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="c-cards__media-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-cards__content">
        <h2>Bærekraft</h2>
        <h3>Bærekraft</h3>
        <h4>Details</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>




Unrelated to the issue, but note that your HTML is invalid. You cannot place a <div> or other block-level elements within an a

Why do your video elements not have the autoplay attribute?

The videos are intentionally designed not to autoplay until the corresponding card is in the foreground (active). Adding the autoplay attribute would undermine this functionality since videos would begin playing immediately regardless of their position in the carousel.
Instead, I’m managing video playback programmatically through JavaScript. When a card becomes active, the video within it starts playing, while videos in other cards are paused and reset to their first frame:

<a>nchors are interactive and so are <video> tags. Interactive elements do behave predictably (if at all) when they are nested within each other.

Have you tried muted as the attribute as opposed to muted="true"?
